# Keeping track of current index when using apply

Tags: r

Wanted to see if someone has a more elegant solution.  But what is the appropriate way to keep track of the current index while using apply.  For example, suppose I wanted to take the sum ONLY from the current element I am evaluating going forward to the end of my vector.

Is this the best way to do it?

```
y = rep(1,100)
apply(as.matrix(seq(1:length(y))),1,function(x) { sum(y[x:length(y)])})
```

I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 10):

This looks more like a task for `sapply`:

```
sapply(seq_along(y), function(x){sum(y[x:length(y)])})
```

For your specific example, there are loads of other options (like reversing the vector `y` and then using `cumsum`), but I guess this is the general pattern:
use `seq_along` or at worst `seq` to get the sequence you are interested in, and pass this  to `*apply`.

Comment: Just a question for clarification of the problem discussed: isn't a for loop more practical if one needs an index? Or am I missing the point here?

Comment: @ROLO: the `*apply` family of function typically can provides very reasonable memory handling for the results, and stores them in a practical form if `simplify=TRUE` (which is not that obvious with these simple examples). Historically, it also used to be so that they were a lot faster than 'normal' loops, but that's not true anymore. So, for simple cases, it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: I feel that cumsum could be very interesting. Could you please elaborate as to how you would implement it inside the sapply ?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the example may have been somewhat unfortunate, but the question how to learn about an index while in the function of "apply" or "sapply" remains unanswered.

Something you may want to look at is

```
x <- 0
l <- 1:10; names(l) <- letters[l]
sapply(l,function(Y) {
   x <<- x+1
   a<-sum(x:length(l))
   cat("I am at ",names(l)[x]," valued ",a,".\n",sep="")
   return(a)
})
```

I am also unhappy, despite the "<<-" trick to reference outer variables (thanks, Stephan). Especially when running in parallel, you want the semantics somehow clearly expressed that request the index or x/y position in sapply or apply. Better ideas are most welcome.

Answer (score 3):

`rev(cumsum(y))` would be a lot faster in the current instance:

```
> y = rep(1,100000)
> system.time(apply(as.matrix(seq(1:length(y))),1,function(x) { sum(y[x:length(y)])}) )
   user  system elapsed 
 88.108  88.639 176.094 
> system.time( rev(cumsum(y)) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.002   0.001   0.004
```

Answer (score 0):

This response has not yet received a satisfactory answer. global variable works such as smoe requested, but it does not seem faster than a for loop, see example below.

```
df=data.frame(a=1:100000,b=1:100000,y=rep(NA,100000))
ind=1
system.time(sapply(df$a,function(x){
  df$y[ind]<<-x+df$b[ind]
  ind<<-ind+1
}))

system.time(for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$y[i]=df$a[i]+df$b[i]
})
```